# What is holding back v8 system memory?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I have a long running SPA, which becomes slow after some time. I already fixed some memory leaks but cannot find anything obvious anymore.

In the test I am currently running, I switch between two page components several times a second. After some time the (system) entry in the memory tab becomes exceedingly large, until the devtools stop execution to prevent an oom kill.

Does anyone have an idea how I can find out, what holds the resources back? Do I have some JS references, keeping them, or is it all chrome internals?

[image: Snapshots diff]
[image: (system) expanded]

- Even after some rest, the heap size doesn't decline
- I have a clean console log, no references kept there

Any help is heavily appreciated

PS. Is there a way to check for biggest arrays existing?

Comment: generally it's because you forgot unsubscribe to an observable, or create a setInterval and not clear or you concat an array each time or...

Comment: that I understand. But how do I find the culprit? As I said, there are no obvious Objects named in the snapshots. Just some of relating to in-memory navigation, but which are just few compared to the thousand times I navigated.